# Calculate $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have to evaluate $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sin z}$. Any tips?

Comment: by definition or residues? Laurent series?

Comment: Or Cauchy's integral formula after writing $$\frac{1}{\sin z} = \frac{\frac{z}{\sin z}}{z}$$

Comment: But z/sinz is not holomorphic in 0

Comment: @luka5z Sure it is. (It just looks like it has a pole there: the singularity is removable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert (far from), but here we go:

One possible solution seems to be using the residue theorem.

$$\int\limits_{\partial B+(O,1)}\frac{\operatorname d z}{\sin z} = 2\pi i \sum_{k} \text{res}_{z=z_k} \frac{1}{\sin z}$$

Which translates into calculating the residues of this function. Since you are integrating over the unit circle there is one pole of order 1 at $z=0$. You can use the Laurent expansion to find the residue.

#### Laurent expansion

$$\frac{1}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\ldots}$$
$$= \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots}$$

We are only interested in the coefficient of the second factor at $z^0$. Because we are working of the unit circle one can state:
$$= \frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)$$

Meaning a residue of $1$ and the integral evaluates to $2\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of not using residue theorem?